adonisjs 6 authentication using object for user model (versus Lucid model)
I am upgrading my adonisjs 5 API to adonisjs 6. Authentication appears to be way different in 6 versus 5. Instead of using a Lucid model for the model proper in sessionUserProvider, I'd like to use an object (i.e. exported interface), since authentication is not done using a database attached to the project (it's using a token from an external project). How can I go about doing so? Below is the code for adonisjs 6's config/auth.ts file. I want to know how to use an object in place of import('#models/user').
import { sessionGuard, sessionUserProvider } from '@adonisjs/auth/session'

const authConfig = defineConfig({
  default: 'web',
  guards: {
    web: sessionGuard({
      useRememberMeTokens: false,
      provider: sessionUserProvider({
        model: () => import('#models/user'),
      }),
    }),
  },
})

export default authConfig

